# Powershell remove duplicates and select last date

Tags: powershell, unique

I have a PS Object with 3 properties:
Status
ID
StartTime

The 'ID' property containts a lot of duplicates. For each unique ID, I only want to select the one with the most recent StartTime. And also important: I want to keep all the properties.

I already did the following:

```
$UniqueList = $CompleteList | Sort-Object -Property ID -Unique
```

This removes the duplicate ID's, but I have no control over which one is kept. I think I have to do something with sorting StartTime and then select -First 1 or something, but I can't get it right in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$UniqueList = $completelist | Group-Object -Property ID | ForEach-Object{$_.Group | Sort-Object -Property StartTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1}
```

Do a Group-Object by ID first, sort them by StartTime in each group, then select -First 1 in each group gives the result.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I had in mind but I just couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a sort on the time property first?

```
$UniqueList = $CompleteList | Sort-Object -Property starttime -Descending | sort-Object -Property ID -Unique
```

Does that have the expected results with your objects?

Comment: That is kind off what I also tried. When I use $UniqueList = $CompleteList | Sort-Object -Property starttime -Descending  everything gets sorted the right way. But when I add the | sort-Object -Property ID -Unique it doesn't use the latest ones.

Comment: It appears to work right for me with get-process. I'd say update your question with the output, but Dong Mao got you with that group/loop approach